# Clone private Mercurial repository on bitbucket.org into InetlliJ IDEA with hg4idea plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial

I created private repository on bitbucket.org. I want to use it from IntelliJ IDEA.

I choose "Check out from Version Control" and there is message box with field `Mercurial Repository URL` and `Test Repository` button.
What should I enter into `Mercurial Repository URL`?

I tried

- `http://bitbucket.org/my_user_name/my_repo_name`,
- `https://`, and `https://my_user_name@bitbucket.org/my_user_name/my_repo_name`.

Nothing works.
When I click `Test Repository` I always get the message "Repository test has failed.".
I assume it is because there is no field for username and password, but can't I enter this data somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Since only the [latest hg4idea](http://bitbucket.org/viacoban/hg4idea/wiki/Changelog) version supports authentication, you could try, for [accessing and cloning your Bitbucket repo](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Cloning+a+Bitbucket+Repository):

```
hg clone http://myuser:mypassword@bitbucket.org/MY_USER/MY_REPO
```

(that is, if your Bitbucket repo is a private one, which you did mention in your question:
'`myuser`' and '`mypassword`' would then be the login and password for your Bitbucket account, using [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for the http url)

Comment: @amorfis: Can you try through `https` (without user or password, since it would only need to find your public key)? (provided you have your public key in `~/.ssh/id_ras.pub`)

Comment: @amorfis: never mind: http://bitbucket.org/viacoban/hg4idea/issue/34/support-for-authentication-on-push-pull "doesn't support ssh authentication based on keys"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by cloning the repository via a command-line prompt using the command that BitBucket gives me on my overview page. After doing that and activating version control on the project in IDEA, IDEA allowed me to push and pull from the repository successfully.